# How to create a HTML link without extension?

Tags: html, hyperlink

Recently I saw in several websites links that are the text of the link and without any extension. The following link (http://www.iicd.org/articles/bolivian-farmers-test-pdas-to-speed-up-organic-certification), for example, the link is the text that is shown in the page but in lower caps and with (-) connecting the words. Is this generated on the fly or how does this work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

These are known as Search Engine Optimized friendly urls. It is either auto-generated or you can do it manually by putting in meaningful folders.
To learn more you can check out details here: http://www.avangate.com/articles/url-rewriting_70.htm

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this works by configuring the webserver in a way that it redirects all access to such URL to a so-called front-controller, a script that decides, which content is to be delivered when such URL is hit.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time it's some CMS like WordPress, Drupal, Joomla, … in the back-end so their structure takes control of creating "pretty permalinks". If you don't use such CMS, you can try to create something like that with .htaccess if you use Linux based server: http://www.sicanstudios.com/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/